# GCM stop working after some time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM service in my app. It is working fine, however some time it stops receiving GCM notifications. I have to restart the device. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523705/gcm-not-received-at-after-idle?rq=1

Comment: U think this is not an issue,some times GCM Masseges are coming let

Comment: Are you sure that restarting the device is necessary? Try turning airplane mode on, then immediately turn it off again. You may well find that the messages come through immediately after doing this.

Comment: Thank you @NickT. This trick worked. But any clue Why is this happening.

Comment: Nothing definitive but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016150/gcm-msg-delivery-times-are-wildly-erratic. I think the delay I experience is attributable to my new ISP and the Virgin Superhub mentioned in one of the answers. Basically a socket gets closed somehow and the airplane mode on/off forces a reopening of it.

Answer (score 1):

This a known problem with some wifi routers and mobile carriers, it's basically a tcp timeout problem and actually  solution is implement a heartbeat service that send to clients every 5 mins.

This a opened issue to google here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/connecting-to-networks-and-devices/fslYqYrULto They agree there is currently an issue.