# simple notification don't appear when my phone in sleep mode

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-wake-lock

i am implementing map place alarm, i successfully getting notification when i am about to reach my destination, but the problem is my phone is in sleep mode, i cant get notification, i don't know how to work with system, plz help me.

here is my code..

```
public class AreWeThereIntentService extends IntentService {

  private final String TAG = AreWeThereIntentService.class.getName();

  private SharedPreferences prefs;
  private Gson gson;

  public AreWeThereIntentService() {
    super("AreWeThereIntentService");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.SharedPrefs.Geofences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    gson = new Gson();

// 1. Get the event
    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (event != null) {
      if (event.hasError()) {
        onError(event.getErrorCode());
      } else {

        // 2. Get the transition type
        int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();
        if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL ||
                transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
          List<String> geofenceIds = new ArrayList<>();

          // 3. Accumulate a list of event geofences
          for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
            geofenceIds.add(geofence.getRequestId());
          }
          if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                  transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
            // 4. Pass the geofence list to the notification method
            onEnteredGeofences(geofenceIds);
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }


  private void onEnteredGeofences(List<String> geofenceIds) {
    // 1. Outer loop over all geofenceIds
    for (String geofenceId : geofenceIds) {
      String geofenceName = "";

      // 2, Loop over all geofence keys in prefs and retrieve NamedGeofence from SharedPreferences
      Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();
      for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        String jsonString = prefs.getString(entry.getKey(), null);
        NamedGeofence namedGeofence = gson.fromJson(jsonString, NamedGeofence.class);
        if (namedGeofence.id.equals(geofenceId)) {
          geofenceName = namedGeofence.name;
          break;
        }
      }

      // 3. Set the notification text and send the notification
      String contextText =
              String.format(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Text), geofenceName);
      // 1. Create a NotificationManager
      NotificationManager notificationManager =
              (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AllGeofencesActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

      Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      long[] pattern = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
// 3. Create and send a notification
      Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
              .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.map_marker_icon)
              .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Title))
              .setContentText(contextText)
              .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
              .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contextText))
              .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
              .setAutoCancel(true)
              .setSound(alarmSound)
              .setVibrate(pattern)
              .build();
      notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
  }

  private void onError(int i) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Geofencing Error: " + i);
  }

}
```

i found solution that i have to use wakelock but i dont know how to use and where i have to implement, what i need is if my notification is still pending then i dont want my phone to sleep, and when i get notification then release wakelock. how do i do that.

Comment: CHECK delay_while_idle should be true

Comment: can you write a code about you talking plz

Comment: It's in PHP side and i don't know php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523705/gcm-not-received-at-after-idle

Comment: You have php file?? for server side??

Comment: no i dont have any php file

Comment: i m simply fetching latitude and longitude using map, and set notification when i reach.. there is no server side coding

Comment: ok so you don't use GCM right??

Comment: no i dont use GCM.. actually i dont need to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method when notification launched

**acquireWakeLock()** : Device wakeup when any new push notification received.

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public  void acquireWakeLock(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
                          context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");

        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public  void releaseWakeLock() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
```